# separate external url for each gitlab-runners

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

### There is a way?

### There is a way?

a host on internet with gitlab-runner
101.987.654.321

gitlab repository with dns name git.ideep.apasaico.local that forwarded to 123.456.789.101:82 valid ip

gitlab-runner hosts file
123.456.789.101  git.ideep.apasaico.local

my shell register runner command
sudo gitlab-runner register --url http://git.ideep.apasaico.local:82/ --registration-token $REGISTRATION_TOKEN

so gitlab-runner are registered and online in gitlab, but because my gitlab external url is on port 80 , when i run job on pipeline , that say repository with port 80 not found.

i need a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You must set the [`clone_url` configuration property](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) in your runner `config.toml` to use the appropriate host/port. This allows you to have a different URL for cloning repositories from the URL used for contacting GitLab to obtain jobs.